# Rails migration referenced id error in generated query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I was using globalize gem and adding some translation tables as done for some models and one of the migrations fails when the **migrate_data: true** option is enable since it tries to access a reference id wrongly generated by the query.

The model that raises this issue is called **GrAmbAdvE**.

I have another one called **GrAmbAdvP** for which i generated the same translation table and all goes well !

The two commands that run in the migrations are:

1. `GrAmbAdvE.create_translation_table!({name: :string, description: :string},{migrate_data: true})`
2. `GrAmbAdvP.create_translation_table!({name: :string, description: :string},{migrate_data: true})`

With 1) get the following error

SELECT "gr_amb_adv_e_translations".* FROM "gr_amb_adv_e_translations" WHERE "gr_amb_adv_e_translations"."gr_amb_adfe_id" = 4 PG::Error: ERROR:  column gr_amb_adv_e_translations.gr_amb_adfe_id does not exist

Index should be `gr_amb_adv_e_id` and is somewhat converted into `gr_amb_adfe_id`

With 2) everything works as expected

SELECT "gr_amb_adv_ps".* FROM "gr_amb_adv_ps" WHERE "gr_amb_adv_ps"."id" = 4

For what is worth i checked if this was a globalize gem issue and i think it's not. If i create the translation table manually and try to access the translations table from the running app i get the same index error.

I would really appreciate any hints that could lead me in the right direction !